# Can't load sound card

Tags: sound, soundcard

I have installed Ubuntu 12 and i cant see any volume control; no audio player can detect any sound card and nothing shown on the System Settings -> Sound -> Output tab.

However, I can see my hardware by typing this command :

```
aplay -l
```

Output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** 
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 1/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U0x4d90x20 [USB Device 0x4d9:0x20], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]   
  Subdevices: 1/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I activate sound ?

Edit:

This info may help for the solution :

```
lspci | grep Audio 

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series]
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your Hardware? What Kind of USB sound device do you use?

Comment: Please also post the output of `lspci -vvv`

Comment: lspci -vvv output is more than one hundred line and sound device is a kind USB that stick to a speaker and One witch in the kvm switch and the one who is in the mainbord .

Comment: OK, try this, edit your question and add the output of this command: sudo lspci | grep Audio

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you like to use?

Try using your Intel Soundcard directly through ALSA:

```
aplay -L
....
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, AD198x Digital
Hardware device with all software conversions
...
```

Lookup your device name and use it as -D argument in speaker-test.

```
speaker-test -Dplughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1 -c 2
```

The Radeon HDMI Audio support is still experimental. You can try using it by editing /etc/default/grub and add radeon.audio=1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Execute update-grup afterwards and reboot.

Comment: I prefer to use USB device and i get result from speaker-test but do you think it is good idea to put it in the grub , why it was working before ,that is what i carius about and where these driver load up ?